# How to position a Node via Group JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I am having some trouble with positioning my button with setLayout of Group in Java FX. My program makes a game with a start button to run it.

My Updated Code:

```
    // Setting the layout of the button
    root.getChildren().get(root.getChildren().size() - 1).setTranslateX(SCENE_WIDTH / 2);
    root.getChildren().get(root.getChildren().size() - 1).setTranslateY(SCENE_HEIGHT / 10);
```

My code assigns Nodes to the Group in this order: Canvas1, Canvas2, Canvas3, Canvas4, Button.

The code above is getting the last Node in the List (Button). The code also has no effect on the button.

So how do I get a Node within the List inside the Group and position it accordingly?

Output:

[image]

Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: `SCENE_HEIGHT / 5` will put the node at about 1/5 the height of the scene, which looks to be where the button is currently. Perhaps you meant `4.0 / 5.0 * SCENE_HEIGHT`? Also, the `layoutX` and `layoutY` values are where the top left corner of the node will be positioned. To properly "center" the node you must take its width and height into account. And you should be using `translateX` and `translateY`, like Sergey's answer says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are using the wrong container (Group) for what you want to accomplish.

How are the four Canvas nodes supposed to appear relative to the start button?
You may want to use an AnchorPane or a VBox.  It all depends on what the total layout should look like.

You might want to consider doing the major layout with SceneBuilder: https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/

Consider also looking at what Group does for layout (not much):
https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/blob/develop/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/javafx/scene/Group.java

You generally don't call setLayoutX/Y unless you are implementing layoutChildren in a new Parent subclass.

Edit:
To stack the Canvas nodes you can place them in a StackPane, but I think I would use an AnchorPane as you can easily anchor the button to be offset from the bottom edge of the AnchorPane.

Comment: I want the canvases to be stacked on top of each other, each adding a layer of Graphics. The button will be on top of it all.

Comment: I used Canvas because setting the background image is easy compared to Stackpane's many parameters just to get an image on there.

Comment: I am using, canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().setFill(ImagePattern for the background);

Answer (score 1):

don't use setLayout, it's used by layout managers which moves children (like StackPane). Group isn't one. Use setTranslateX instead.